# Отображение картинки через QGraphicPixmapItem

Tags: python, python-3.x, изображения, pyqt

Прошу помочь мне, я пишу `GUI` для отображения картинок (`Python3` + `PyQt5`).
 В первоначальном варианте использовал `QLabel` и `Pixmap`, но захотелось отлавливать движение мыши, чтобы в последствии менять картинку. И подумал, что это возможно, с помощью `QGraphicPixmapItem`. Но движение мышки у меня никак не отлавливается.

Далее приведу схематичный код.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QGraphicsItem
# и еще всякие разные импорты

# далее идет класс с Qt
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.GraphicPixmap = QtWidgets.QGraphicsPixmapItem()
        self.GraphicPixmap.setAcceptHoverEvents(True) #метод разрешает обработку событий 
        self.scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene()
        self.scene.addItem(self.GraphicPixmap)
        self.graphicsView = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(self.scene, self.centralwidget)
        #далее идет куча всякого Qt

class MainWindow_class(Ui_MainWindow, QMainWindow, QGraphicsItem):
    # класс со всякими функциями логики работы программы
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

    # функция должна отлавливать движение мышки по scene
    def hoverMoveEvent(self, event):
        print(event.pos())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = MainWindow_class()
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Основная идея с мышкой - хочу кликая по картинке менять её (картинка представляет из себя нарисованный график, который будет меняться интреактивно). Может кто знает как красиво добавить какой-нибудь `matplotlib` с элементами анимации?

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо **зарегистрировать** Ваш метод `hoverMoveEvent` в одном или нескольких [hover-обработчиках](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#hoverEnterEvent) (`hoverEnterEvent`, `hoverLeaveEvent`, `hoverMoveEvent`).

Тогда метод `__init__` будет иметь вид:

```
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.setupUi(self)
    self.GraphicPixmap.hoverMoveEvent = self.hoverMoveEvent
    self.GraphicPixmap.hoverEnterEvent = self.hoverMoveEvent
    self.GraphicPixmap.hoverLeaveEvent = self.hoverMoveEvent
```

Для тестирования предварительно разместил `Pixmap` в `GraphicPixmap`:

```
self.pixmap = QPixmap("715.gif")
self.GraphicPixmap.setPixmap(self.pixmap)
```

Тестировалось на Python 3.6, PyQt5 5.8.0, Windows 7 64-bit

Comment: А как будет выглядеть описание метода `hoverMoveEvent`?

Comment: @gil9red, метод `hoverMoveEvent` остаётся ровно таким же, как в исходном сообщении.

Comment: `@staticmethod def hoverEnterEvent(self, event)` ?

Comment: Да, всё верно http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#hoverEnterEvent

Comment: `@staticmethod` тут вроде не нужен